# AngularJS and JavaScript boot order

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The script code in my html loads before my AngularJS controller does. Is there any way that I can get the Angular controller to boot before the javascript in the html so I can access the AngularJS variable that I need from the html script block?

Comment: can you provide your example, that would help more.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script block at the bottom of the body tag.

i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
     <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="angularJS"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <script type="otherscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```